# Find WCF service certificate, using several search criteria in config file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, x509certificate

I'm wondering, is there any way to find WCF service certificate, using several search criteria in `.config` file?

E.g., if I want to find certificate by subject name, then my config will contain these lines:

```
        <serviceCertificate findValue="host.domain.com"
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                            storeName="My"
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
```

And what should I put in the config file, if I want to find a certificate by subject name **and** by application policy?

I know, that `X509Certificate2Collection` class [allows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find) this:

```
            return store
                .Certificates
                .Find(X509FindType.FindByApplicationPolicy, "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1", false)
                .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "host.domain.com", false)
                .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
```

And what about `.config`-files?

Comment: The example in the `X509Certificate2Collection.Find` documentation only shows a Find by TimeValid (`X509FindType.FindByTimeValid`). I don't see where you can do a Find by application policy. The only parameter from the sample code that isn't available in the configuration is the `OpenFlags` used in the `X509Store.Open` call, WCF should have default for this, I guess.

Comment: This configuration block probably calls the X509CertificateRecipientServiceCredential.SetCertificate method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576355.aspx), and all there is no other available parameters.

Comment: @Paciv: the question isn't about `X509Certificate2Collection.Find`. It allows to find by application policy, just believe me (see the updated question). :) The question is about how to make search criteria chaining in config file, like in code.

Comment: Sorry, I changed a bit my answer while you accepted it (adding a way to do it from configuration rather than code).Please check if the updated solution is still valid.

Comment: @Paciv: thanks, it seems to me, this solution will help. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a custom service behavior and you will be able to provide your application policy AND subject name from configuration, executing two consecutive find on the certificate store.

```
public class ServerCertificateServiceBehavior : IServiceBehavior
{
    private X509Certificate2 certificate;

    public ServerCertificateServiceBehavior(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, string subjectName, string applicationPolicy)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);

        certificate = store
            .Certificates
            .Find(X509FindType.FindByApplicationPolicy, applicationPolicy, false)
            .Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, subjectName, false)
            .Cast<X509Certificate2>()
            .SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        serviceHostBase.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.Certificate = this.certificate;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) { }
    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase) { }
}
```

The ExtensionElement :

```
public class ServerCertificateServiceBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("applicationPolicy", IsRequired = true)]
    public string ApplicationPolicy
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["applicationPolicy"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["applicationPolicy"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("subjectName", IsRequired = true)]
    public string SubjectName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base["subjectName"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["subjectName"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("storeLocation", DefaultValue = 2)]
    public StoreLocation StoreLocation
    {
        get
        {
            return (StoreLocation)base["storeLocation"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["storeLocation"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("storeName", DefaultValue = 5)]
    public StoreName StoreName
    {
        get
        {
            return (StoreName)base["storeName"];
        }
        set
        {
            base["storeName"] = value;
        }
    }

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(ServerCertificateServiceBehavior); }
    }
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new ServerCertificateServiceBehavior(
                this.StoreName, 
                this.StoreLocation, 
                this.SubjectName, 
                this.ApplicationPolicy);
    }
}
```

The configuration becomes :

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="YourServiceBehaviorConfiguration">
      <!-- ... -->
      <serverCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                         storeName="My"
                         subjectName="host.domain.com"
                         applicationPolicy="1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="serverCertificate" type="Extensions.ServerCertificateServiceBehaviorExtensionElement, Extensions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Comment: I don't know how your code would've worked, since even in the latest .net 4.7 the `FindByApplicationPolicy` is still not supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection.find?view=netframework-4.7

Comment: @codenamezero In Mono it seems yes. It should work on Windows... Certificate Store are very OS / Run-time Environment dependent.